# How to create a box for user input and then store it as a variable in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, raspberry-pi3, mobile-development

I'm totally new to Java and Android Studio. I wanted to know how to create a box dialogue or whatever the correct term is to create a box where the user can type and whatever he writes will be stored under a variable?

Context: I'm creating a home security device. The purpose of the app would be for the user to insert their phone number so they could get SMS notifications on the state of their doors that is monitored by external sensors on a Raspberry Pi. Once I know how to take in user input in Android studio and save it under a variable I can then save it to a file and using Python read from that file and then do whatever I need to with the phone number. Ideally, I understand this would have been done in just Java but learning another language with my novice understanding at this stage is too slow to make this project happen on time, hope you understand and ignore my lack of knowledge in this area.

Thanks ahead!

Comment: Show some code that you've written so far...

Comment: TL; DR. Please show some code.